# Can I use adb to change the default launcher program?

Tags: android

I set one of the program as default launcher program and default setting program so I cannot change the default programs now, can I change the default programs from `android-sdk\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe` or remote shell.

How can I do that?

And can I remove the defaults of program in Java code?

Comment: Please refer to this link for precise answer: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/142880/setting-default-applications-through-adb

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you can remove (Uninstall) the default program you set using **ADB** by doing this :

```
adb uninstall app.package  ..... //for example (com.example.homeapp)
```

If you don't want to remove the app .. here is a quick hack to do it:

- adb shell
- am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN

That way you will have a picker with all apps on your devices that listens to *Main* Action

- Choose any home screen app you want . then go to settings and set it as default.

Comment: Just tested a way you can use to achieve what you want

Comment: you saved my job boss :)

Comment: I understood the question to be how to change the launcher with adb without having to uninstall / install

Comment: Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve intent { act=android.intent.action.main flag=0x10000000 } @Mr.Me

Comment: adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN }
Security exception: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.setupui.VpaSelectionOptionalStepActivity } from null (pid=22627, uid=2000) requires com.android.vending.setup.PLAY_SETUP_SERVICE

Comment: adb -s 192.168.1.218:5555 shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN
produces 
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.setupui.VpaSelectionOptionalStepActivity } from null (pid=7314, uid=2000) requires com.android.vending.setup.PLAY_SETUP_SERVICE

However, entering the shell then su, then am command says "Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN }" but nothing (app picker) appeared on the device screen?

Comment: never mind this hack (stupidly long command) worked
adb -s 192.168.1.218:5555 shell cmd package set-home-activity com.hisight.mslauncher/com.hisight.mslauncher.MainActivity

Answer (score 22):

For system apps you can't uninstall, use pm disable as in

`adb shell pm disable com.android.launcher`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, use adb shell to disable one of the launcher apps that you do not want.

Comment: Trying to disable the system launcher, I get: Error: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial

Comment: Yeah, the problem is the default system launcher.

Comment: Thanks, needed this to disable `com.android.server.telecom` and `com.android.dialer`

Comment: @BrentK. @rage , there is sometimes problem with permissions...
Try `adb shell pm disable-user --user 0 [launcher.app]` to prevent it from starting after reboot...
For example i use `adb shell pm disable-user --user 0 com.android.systemui` to prevent systemUI from showing up (home,back,tasks buttons and notifications bar are not starting after reboot)

Comment: @MykolaKikets solution worked for me. In my case what worked for me was `adb shell su ` and then repeatedly run `adb shell pm disable-user --user 0 ru.softcomlan.kioskmodelauncher` until it succeeded while starting up the device (in my case the launcher was disabling adb when started)

Answer (score 13):

adb shell cmd package set-home-activity "package/activity"

adb reboot

Comment: `/system/bin/sh: cmd: not found` What android version do you need for this to work? Where do you get `cmd`? EDIT: It doesn't work on API 19 but works on API 24 emulator.

Comment: correct, sorry I failed to mention this was recently added

Comment: I followed the source to [PackageManagerShellCommand](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/nougat-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerShellCommand.java) and [PackageManagerService#setHomeActivity](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/3de09838fb0996bb4b420630800ad34e828fd1b6/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java#L17629) and yes, it's been added in API 24. But more importantly it looks pretty hooked up to system so **reboot shouldn't be necessary**.

Comment: What's "package/activity"? I get error component can be home on user 0

Comment: The command actually is
    `adb shell pm set-home-activity "package/activity"`
where package/activity has to be substituted by package name/main activity of the desired launcher. The command is available from API 24/Nougat/Android 7

Comment: This must be the accepted answer. Anyway `adb reboot` may not be needed in some devices (with Samsung SM-T813 you just have to press the home button). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The key is adb. Once you know the package name of the app you wish to clear data for, try:

```
adb shell pm clear package.name.of.app
```

It'll clear all data for the app, but I don't know of a way to only clear the defaults.

Answer (score 1):

You can check and change the default sms app by using `adb shell settings get secure sms_default_application` and then use `adb shell settings put secure sms_default_application <package name>`. I'm not sure about the other default apps, but it's just a matter of finding it with `adb shell settings list <secure/system/global>`